# How to insert JavaScript Code in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, blogger

Anyone can help me. I have problem with my blog.

I want to input slicky slider on homepage blogger. I have script fromm codepen : https://codepen.io/jamy/pen/gbdWGJ

my question is, how to input this script on blogger template.

```
var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true,
  wrapAround: true,
  prevNextButtons: false,
  autoPlay: 5000
});
```

I try same option but always failed. thx

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for an answer. Finally, steep maybe like this:

1. put this code external Flickity before the tag

```html
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.0.0/flickity.pkgd.min.js' type='text/javascript' />
```

2. and Flickity function after or bellow ""

```js
< script type = 'text/javascript' >
  //<![CDATA[
  var flkty = new Flickity('.main-gallery', {
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    prevNextButtons: false,
    autoPlay: 5000
  });
//]]>
<
/script>
```

3. Finally step add the following CSS :

```css
/* ---- page dots ---- */
.flickity-page-dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

.flickity-rtl .flickity-page-dots { direction: rtl; }

.flickity-page-dots .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.25;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code use a Flickity function and you need to add external Flickity files in your template.

Put this in the head and before your code

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.0.0/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but 
I've done that. but still can not. Do you have any option?

Comment: No, i use html, css and js directly input in (edit html template). i try put this code before </head> or inside <body> but still can not

Comment: Ok, can you check this code i screenshot : https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-__V5zeA56Bg/WLjb2kYCRmI/AAAAAAAAAEc/mhwdj_ZNLhwQzbPSdPKNLdws2yq5S129ACLcB/s1600/js%2Bflickty.png  
is there something wrong

Comment: The code is fine but you need to link Flickity files in your template see answer update

Comment: i just add the code : https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Dwu6j0Ezj60/WLjinHiRhTI/AAAAAAAAAEs/RVaqdiG0ve05x2kBw1nQvPeuTJLekG49wCLcB/s1600/j.png   but still can not.

Comment: @Rohmat rather than inserting this code just before the `</head>` tag, insert it just before the `</body>` tag as it seems that Flickity is unable to find the element (It throws the error - `Bad element for Flickity: .main-gallery`). Or you wrap the call to Flickity in a `document.ready` block(refer to https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ )

Comment: hy @PrayagVerma thans for suggestion, i just try to put code before the </body> and the script could running but the css same error. please visit : aqiqoh-syafaat.blogspot.co.id

Comment: @Rohmat The CSS for the plugin is missing, insert it into your blog to resolve this issue. The CSS to include would be - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.0.5/flickity.min.css" />` Refer to https://cdnjs.com/libraries/flickity in case you want the CSS of a different version of the plugin

Comment: when i change js not running again. i just delete the bullet and add css overflow hidden only.  for all thanks for respons and answer. sorry for bad english. :)